# how to write a batch file using file inputs as a variable in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I know c++ pretty well and unix commands (bourn shell) fairly well, but I am very unfamiliar with batch files.

I'm working on getting serial numbers for all of our machines to verify that they are named properly, and are issued to the correct user. Please note that this is my first post and am just giving you the down and dirty code.

This is what I have so far (good for one computer)

```
hostname >> computerlog.txt    rem send the pcname to txtfile computerlog

    rem get serial number from bios
wmic bios get serialnumber >> computerlog.txt 

    rem get serial number from network location (pcname is a network pc)
wmic /user:johnnyboy/node:pcname bios get serialnumber >> computerlog.txt
```

What I would like to do is use a loop to read the names in and store them as a variable, run the command above, and output the name followed by serial number to a text file.

I don't know how to use a loop or create a variable.
Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the data in the file YourData.csv has this format

```
"NODENAME","USERNAME","PASSWORD"
"Computer1","Johnnyboy","secret"
```

This batch should do what you want:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
(Echo "NODENAME","SerialNumber"
 For /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in (
     "YourData.csv"
 ) Do  For /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%S in (
         'wmic /NODE:%%A /USER:%%B /PASSWORD:%%C bios get serialnumber /value^|find "="'
       ) Do For /f "delims=" %%T in ("%%S") Do Echo %%A,"%%T"
) > "YourSerials.csv"
```

Since the wmic output is in UTF16 and one for loop can't compensate the conversion remnants `cr,cr,lf` the third for will do this.

Sample output:

```
> type YourSerials.csv
"NODENAME","SerialNumber"
"HP-G1610","CZxxxyyyPM      "
```

Be warned that wmic here was terribly slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
snippets:
set "varName=varValue"
:loopName
:: do something
goto:loopName
:: take each line of log to %%t - variable of cycle
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%t in ("computerlog.txt") do echo.%%t

example:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%t in ("computerlog.txt") do (
    set "var!counter!=%%t"
    set /a counter+=1
)
set var
```

Comment: Ok I see how the loop syntax is, but how about an input from a file, I tried using /p but it kept throwing out echo ......bunch of junk.......